# How can I Pay Azure Bill Before It's Due Day?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Pay-as-you-go billing account. I've used resources with that account. Now I want to pay it before it's due date. Is it possible if so how can I do it? And what happens if it goes past due?

Answer (score 0):

If your payment isn't received or if we can't process your payment, you will get an email and see an alert in the Azure portal telling you that your subscription is past due. If your default payment method is credit card, the Account Administrator can settle the outstanding charges in the Azure portal. If you pay by invoice (check/wire transfer), send your payment to the location listed at the bottom of your invoice.

If I forget to pay, The service is canceled and your resources are no longer available. Your Azure data is deleted 90 days after the service is terminated.

For how to pay bill check [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/understand/pay-bill).